# How to shutdown op-amps for low-power standby

Tags: mosfet, low-power

What is the best way to shut down the analog front end of my sensor system for a low-power standby mode. My circuit is battery powered via a 3.3V buck/boost converter I would like my STM32 microcontroller to shutdown the analog circuitry (op-amps) before going into low-power mode. Is this as simple as putting a MOSFET switch on my AVDD rail controlled by a GPIO pin? Should specialty power switching ICs be used? The combined current draw of the analog circuitry is only around 1mA but will deplete the battery for long standby intervals.

Comment: Maybe consider a much lower power op-amp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe. You have to realize that the inputs (or even output if there is a pull-up) may power the op-amp through protection networks. If that is not an issue, then a high-side (eg. P-channel) MOSFET or PNP works fine. Some op-amps allow inputs in excess of the supply voltage, which is nice when your supply voltage is zero.

Depending on your application you may wish to consider an op-amp that has a power-down input. That allows the Vdd to be maintained, but puts the amplifier in a low power consumption mode.

Comment: Good point about the input protection. I have an AD8226 instrumentation amp with 1.8V across its input even with power removed. I could not determine if this is allowed from the datasheet but in practice I don't see any leakage when supply is removed.

Answer (score 1):

> The combined current draw of the analog circuitry is only around 1mA

Then, sure you can use a FET, but you can also power it from a microcontroller GPIO used as an output, it won't have any trouble outputting 1mA. Note this saves a FET but it will output the internal VCC of the micro, which may be noisy.

If you have some unused logic gates or inverters in your design, you can also use one of these to supply your opamps.

If your opamps use biasing resistors connected to the positive supply, these must also go to the switched supply. Don't just switch the supply of the opamp.